# Prove $\Gamma g_\varepsilon (0) = O( |\varepsilon |^k) $ as $ \varepsilon \to 0$, where $g$ is a smooth function, $\Gamma$ the difference operator

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, finite-differences, smooth-functions

We consider $d \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose $q : \mathbb{Z}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is a finite supported function and there's some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $l \in \{ 1, ....k-1 \} $ and all $j_1 , ...j_l \in \{1, ...d\}$, we have
$$
  (*) \sum_{x = (x_1 ,x_2 , ...x_d ) \in \mathbb{Z}^d} x_{j_1} ....x_{j_2} q(x) = 0
$$

We define the kth order difference operator $\Gamma$ acting upon real functions $f$ by
$$
\Gamma f (x) = \sum_{ y \in \mathbb{Z}^d} f(x+y) q(y),
$$

The problem is

> Prove that $\Gamma g_\varepsilon (0)  =  O(  |\varepsilon|^k ) $ as $ \varepsilon \to 0$, where $g: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, $\Gamma$ is a kth order difference operator, and $ g_\varepsilon (x) = g( \varepsilon x)$.

If we consider, for example, $d =1$, $k = 2$, and $ q (1) = q(-1) = 1/2$, $q(0) = 1$, and $q = 0$ otherwise. Then we obtain that the corresponding difference operator satisfies
$$
  \Gamma f (x)  = \frac{ f(x+ 1)+ f(x - 1)}{2}   - f(x) ,
$$
which is the second order difference of $f$ at $x$.In this particular case, we can use the Mean Value theorem to conclude the desired result. However, I have no idea how to generalize the result for any $q$ satisfying $(*)$. Could anyone provide a solution to it?

Comment: My first guess would be that your condition on $q$ allows you to write something like $\Gamma f(0)= \Gamma (f-T_{f,0})(0)$ where $T_{f,0}$ is the Taylor polynomial of some fixed degree, based at 0.

Comment: @Jose27 I'm not sure whether we can use Taylor's polynomial to approximate the original difference equation, since in this problem we only have the assumption that the function is smooth, instead of being real analytic.